# How to round numbers

Tags: python, rounding

How would I be able to round numbers like these to two decimal places which are all stored in a variable which has been outputted by a web scraper:

```
4.7532
4.7294
4.7056
4.6822857142857
4.65868
4.63522
4.6119866666667
4.58898
4.566064
4.543216
```

I am new to python so i'm not sure. I'm using Python 2

Comment: you have a builtin fun round()

Comment: Just one personal thought, use Python 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the built-in function [round()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round), example:

```
>>> round(4.7532,2)
4.75
>>> round(4.7294,2)
4.73
```

Comment: TypeError: a float is required, I'm not sure what this means?

Comment: @Ando make sure the type of your variable is float, if it's a string (ex: num='4.7532'), convert it to float number first and pass to round(): round(float(num),2)

Comment: @Ando `float` is a built-in numeric type in python. The function `round()` only accepts floats or integers as input. You get an error message when you try this `round("3.14")` instead of `round(3.14)`

Comment: Python 3 has a more helpful error message:
`TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method`

Answer (score 1):

I think from what you say, you have a single string containing these numbers, and you want to print them out as 2dp formatted?

If so, the first thing to do is split the single string into an array, and convert to floating point numbers

```
numstr = """4.7532
4.7294
4.7056
4.6822857142857"""

nums = [float(x) for x in numstr.split("\n")]
```

This gives us an array of floating point python numbers

Now, we want to output them, having rounded. We can do that a few ways, the easiest is probably

```
for num in nums:
    print "%0.2f" % num
```

That will loop over all your numbers, and print them out one per line, formatted to two decimal places